# enqueue style google fonts in functions.php in array?

Tags: user-registration

I have a list of 300 fonts from google fonts and try to register in function.php via wp_enqueue_style. Is there any possibility to do this with a variable?
Example:

```
$font_link =  $style_font_standard = array(
           "none" => "Select a font",//please, always use this key: "none"
           "Arial" => "Arial",
           "Actor" => "Actor",
           "Abel" => "Abel",
           "Allura" => "Allura",
           "Advent Pro" => "Advent Pro",
           ...ect
```

);

```
$enque_font = implode('|', $font_link);

    wp_enqueue_style( 'google-fonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family='. $enque_font, false, '', 'all' );
```

code probably is not good I need help ...

Comment: You're going to enqueue **300** different font links into your WordPress?

Comment: Total overkill. Why so much?

Comment: Maybe he wants to provide a theme option for an admin to choose from or something, there are valid use cases for this.

Comment: What's the problem ? What results you get?

Comment: Regardless of whether or not there are valid use-cases for doing something like this, I think we can all agree to **strongly** recommend against it - a single font often exceeds 50KB and many surpass 100... we're talking about loading **more than 14-30MB of fonts** in a single page load. That's more data than an entire WP installation. Whatever you're attempting to accomplish, there is almost certainly a better way to achieve it. Lazy-load them as needed, pre-render font previews into images, etc. Strive to avoid hitting end-users with a 30MB font download when the content only uses 0.07MB O.o

Answer (score 0):

Each time you use wp_enqueue_style, they each need their own unique ID. So 'google-fonts' isn't going to work with:

**wp_enqueue_style( 'google-fonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family='. $enque_font, false, '', 'all' );**

And you have two variables set up for the array?

**$font_link =  $style_font_standard = array(**

I wrote it as one variable and in the array, they have pairs, so I'm assuming the left side was meant for the unique IDs and the right side, for the link that gets inserted after 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family='.

And with arrays, instead of implode, tell WordPress what to do with each pair of values you have using a for each. Here's what I have. I'm not sure if it will work for what you're planning but at the very least, it starts you off by enquequeing the css like you wanted.

```
$style_font_standard = array(
   "none" => "Select a font",//please, always use this key: "none"
   "Arial" => "Arial",
   "Actor" => "Actor",
   "Abel" => "Abel",
   "Allura" => "Allura",
   "Advent Pro" => "Advent Pro");

foreach($style_font_standard as $fontstyle => $fontlink) {
wp_enqueue_style( $fontstyle, 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family='. $fontlink, false, '', 'all' );
```

}

Hope that helps. There's a free video on TutsPlus that helps explain arrays better:

https://tutsplus.com/lesson/arrays-part-1/

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for the link tutsplus helped me a lot. I need a theme settings options in the customizer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link tutsplus helped me a lot. I need a theme settings options in the customizer.  Result is  worcks weell see foto: http://postimg.org/image/j1904hofh/

Comment: You're welcome - happy it helped. Tutsplus is a great source. :-) If my answer resolved your problem, mind marking it correct for anyone in the future that might face the same issue?

Comment: You only need one `wp_enqueue_style`. You can load as many Google font as you want with one URL - as in the question - you just seperate the family names with a `|`